# Fix a NaN output to show the correct value

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

The code was originally working perfectly fine one week ago, the code for some reason decides on not working today. It is a future warning, however, when trying to read the file, it does not function.

I've already tried removing some variables, but it has never done this.

```
drug1 = drug.loc[:, ["DUQ200", "DUQ210", "DUQ211", "DUQ213", "DUQ215Q", "DUQ215Q", "DUQ215U", "DUQ217", "DUQ219", "DUQ220Q", "DUQ220U", "DUQ230", "DUQ240", "DUQ250", "DUQ260", "DUQ270Q" , "DUQ270U", "DUQ272", "DUQ280" "DUQ290","DUQ300", "DUQ310Q", "DUQ310U", "DUQ320", "DUQ330", "DUQ340", "DUQ350Q", "DUQ350U", "DUQ352", "DUQ360" "DUQ370", "DUQ380A", "DUQ380B", "DUQ380C", "DUQ380D", "DUQ380E", "DUQ390", "DUQ400Q", "DUQ400U", "DUQ410", "DUQ420", "DUQ430"]]

drug2 = drug1.dropna()
for i in ["DUQ200", "DUQ240", "DUQ250", "DUQ290", "DUQ330", "DUQ370", ]:
    print(drug2[i].value_counts()/drug2.count())
```

The expected result is some data, the actual result is "NaN" for all of the variables.

Comment: `drug1 = drug.loc[:, []].copy()`